# Do we have anything like @AfterScenario in Karate?

Tags: java, bdd, karate

I would like to call a method after each scenario from a single Feature with Karate, do we have something like `@AfterScenario` in Karate? Or is there any other way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an `afterScenario` hook. Please refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

```
* configure afterScenario = function(){ karate.log('hi') }
```

Comment: Whether Karate.config.js process the After scenario for each scenario? If not, we need to call the after scenario in all the feature file.

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan yes

Comment: The **YES** is for call the scenario in all the feature file?

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan yes. (I'm being as vague as your question. ask a new (good) question if needed)

Comment: What he is asking is if there is an place where you can put afterScenario so that you don't have to put it in each feature file.  I see that karate-config.js is run BEFORE every scenario. That may be sufficient to add it using karate.configure("afterScenario", "function(){ karate.log('hi') }")

Comment: @PeterThomas  That didn't work when I just tried using Karate 0.9.6

Comment: @PBMax follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Did you considered using new sections like “BeforeScenario” (current Background), “AfterScenario”, “BeforeFeature” (call once) and AfterFeature”? Its a bit confusing mixing all of them in the Background section and also it’s confusing to mix calls in Background (* call …) with functions containing calls inside (like afterScenario). All these things should be unified, now it looks like patches and workarounds.

Comment: @VictoriaAntolucci agreed, hooks are advanced things that you shouldn't do within a feature file. for full control, the recommendation is to write Java code as the `RuntimeHook`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475