# Karate afterFeature function execution works fine when run locally but fails when run through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, karate

Karate [afterFeature](https://github.com/intuit/karate/#hooks) function execution works fine when run locally but fails when run through Jenkins, I get `assertion failed: assert evaluated to false: responseStatus == 200 || responseStatus == 404`. Whereas the `responseStatus` should either be `200 or 404`.

**Code Snippet**

**main.feature snippet**

```
  Background:
    ...
    * def myName1 = 'karate-test-name'
    * configure afterFeature = function(){ karate.call('cleanup.feature'); }
  ...
  ...
```

**cleanup.feature**

```
@ignore
Feature: To cleanup after main.feature execution. This Feature is not supposed to be run individually.

  Background:
    * url myUrl

  Scenario: Delete
    * print 'In "cleanup.feature", If exists delete: ' + myName1
    Given path 'v1/myapi/',myName1,''
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    And request {}
    When method delete
    Then assert responseStatus == 200 || responseStatus == 404
```

**Logs from Jenkins:**
The assertion for the `responseStatus` fails, but it does not log the actual value of the *responseStatus*.

```
23:03:15.448 [pool-1-thread-4] ERROR com.intuit.karate - assertion failed: assert evaluated to false: responseStatus == 200 || responseStatus == 404
23:03:15.450 [pool-1-thread-4] ERROR com.intuit.karate - feature call failed: cleanup.feature
arg: null
cleanup.feature:16 - assert evaluated to false: responseStatus == 200 || responseStatus == 404
23:03:15.451 [pool-1-thread-4] ERROR com.intuit.karate - javascript function call failed: 
cleanup.feature:16 - assert evaluated to false: responseStatus == 200 || responseStatus == 404
23:03:15.451 [pool-1-thread-4] ERROR com.intuit.karate - failed function body: function(){ karate.call('cleanup.feature'); }
```

Moreover, I do not see the logs for execution of *afterFeature* in Jenkins, neither it is part of the Cucumber report for me to do further analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely an old version of Karate. Try 0.9.5

If you still can't solve this - please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

And also, please read this for other options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475

Comment: +1 I went ahead with your suggestion to pre-clean-up instead of using `afterFeature` and  I do see `responseStatus` set correctly in there.