# Is there any hook for after all features?

Tags: karate

So in karate we can set some global hooks in karate-config to execute before each scenario, or execute before all scenarios with callonce.
Is there a way to do the opposite? and execute steps after each scenario or after all scenarios?

I want something global that applies to all files (potentially in karate-config), and not rewrite the same afterScenario/afterFeature in each file

Comment: please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475