# Karate - Customize what gets printed after each scenario globally

Tags: testing, karate, web-api-testing

So, to help track issues, we send back a `call-id` in response header. We use `karate` for API test automation. We want to print the `call-id` after each scenario. I know how to print this at the scenario level. We have around 300 scenarios in our test suite and we want to know if there is way to configure something in `karate-config.js` which can print the response header fields to the console and the html reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`karate.configure('afterScenario', function(){})` should work, so you can try that. Else I recommend using hooks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475