# Is there any way in karate to execute some operations after suit

Tags: api, user-interface, karate

Suppose I have created a client before executing the suit (which contains multiple feature files)---> at the end of this suit I want to perform some operations i.e, after_suit(delete created client) -> we know about after scenario, after feature, but need to know how to use **after suit in karate**
is it possible in karate? **as in selenium we have @aftersuit  annotation.**

Comment: @PeterThomas will you suggest something related to it

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475