# How to execute a Karate.exec() in AfterAll annotation in Karate Runner

Tags: karate

I have to execute a task after all the tests have run in karate. So i was trying to add @AfterAll annotation to the Karate Runner and defined a function to do the task of executing a python script by using karate.exec(), but it was showing an error that cannot resolve symbol karate.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this answer has all available info on this subject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475

Comment: Sorry @PeterThomas, i did not find the relevant answer to my question for the above post.

Comment: sorry, I have no other suggestions, maybe someone else can chime in