# how to run the specific steps after the scenario completion always even though test passes or fails?

Tags: testing, automation, karate, karate-call-single

In Karate Framework, how to run the specific steps after the scenario completion always even though test passes or fails?

how to run the specific steps after the scenario completion always even though test passes or fails?

Comment: this is what hooks are for: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#hooks

Comment: I want to run the database query and delete the data i created in the scenario.. is it possible in after scenario hooks?

Comment: it may be - but not recommended, read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475