# afterFeature steps not coming up in karate and cucumber output reports

Tags: karate

I am implementing afterFeature for my test suite. I can see that afterFeature is calling the separate feature file which I want to call and also can see the logs printing into console as well. When I am checking the output karate and cucumber report, I do not see the steps. So I was wondering is there a way to add the steps to karate or cucumber report? I am using karate 1.4 version with Junit 5. Also running the tests in parallel. I can also see that afterScenario steps are coming up in the report. It's just afterFeature steps are not coming up in the report.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a limitation or bug in Karate. We don't recommend using `afterfeature` for anything that you see in the report, it is meant for cleanup and other integrations.

I think your best bet is to not depend on it or contribute code to improve Karate on this front. It is certainly not a priority for the project right now.

Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475