# afterFeature test scenarios steps aren't coming in reports generated by Karate

Tags: cucumber, report, karate

I have three feature files - preTest.feature,postTest.feature and tests.fetaure. I'm doing callonce for preTest.feature and configured afterFeature for postTest.feature in tests.feature. These two called feature files are getting executed fine but in report detailed steps aren't coming of both preTest.feature and postTest.feature files. Steps are coming only of tests.feature.
How to show all steps even called feature files in Karate report?

### preTest.feature

```
Feature: Pre test suite test cases
    Background:
        * print 'setup tasks'
    Scenario:
        Given url URL
        When method 'GET'
        Then status == 200 

    Scenario:
        Given url URL
        When method 'GET'
        Then status == 200
```

### postTest.feature

```
Feature: Post test suite test cases
    Background:
        * print 'clean up tasks'
    Scenario:
        Given url URL
        When method 'GET'
        Then status == 200 

    Scenario:
        Given url URL
        When method 'GET'
        Then status == 200
```

### tests.feature

```
Feature: Test suite test cases
    Background:
        * print 'all test cases'
        * def dataReturnedFromPreSetupTests = callonce read('classpath:preTest.feature')
        * configure afterFeature = function(){ karate.call('classpath:postTest.feature',             preSetupData); }

    Scenario:
        Given url URL
        When method 'GET'
        Then status == 200 

    Scenario:
        Given url URL
        When method 'GET'
        Then status == 200
```

I tried putting Gerkin keyword too for called feature files but it dint work for me.
For example added below line in tests.feature -

```
When def dataReturnedFromPreSetupTests = callonce read('classpath:preTest.feature')
```

Comment: please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76723165/143475

Comment: If I add @report=true in preTest.feature and postTest.feature (called feature files) then will step details of these files come in report?

Comment: besides what is shared in the above link - I am not sure. you can try or contribute code. I request you and your team to think: are you testing or creating reports ? which is more important :)