# Karate call scenario from Backgound "afterFeature" hook

Tags: javascript, karate

I have a feature file with common api calls, which can look like this:

```
Feature: common user api calls

    Background:
        Given url userUrl

    @createUser @ignore
    Scenario: Create user
        And match karate.get('name') != null
        And def requestBody = read('classpath:user/json/request.json')

        And request requestBody
        When method post
        Then status 201
```

in my karate-config.js I have this line to define global function:

```
config.userCommon = function(tag){ return karate.read("classpath:user/userCommon.feature" + tag) };
```

I can call that @createUser scenario from another scenario like this:

```
Feature: User Tests

    Scenario: Create user test
         And def name = 'aa'
         And call userCommon('@createUser') { "name": '#(name)' }
```

But I would like to call that @createUser scenario in the Background in "afterFeature" hook, how can I do that?

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
Feature: User Tests

    Background:
        * configure afterFeature =
            """
            function(){
                var create = userCommon('@createUser');
                karate.call(create, { name: 'aa' });
            }
            """
```

Comment: it is probably some mistake in your setup or a bug in karate, so follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - also take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475