# How to call an API after all the features files at been executed in Karate?

Tags: karate

My karate tests created new users in my database. The API to create these users is call in karate-config.js. The users are used by many feature files. I want to call an API to delete these user at the very end of the test execution (when all feature files are done). How can I do that?

I looked in the Karate documentation, but I didn't find any after hook that I can apply at the very end of the execution (and not only at the end of a feature file).

I saw this issues : [Dynamic scenario freezes when called using afterFeature hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943891/dynamic-scenario-freezes-when-called-using-afterfeature-hook) , but it's not the same case. In my case, I want to call the after scenario at the very end, after ALL features has been executed (and not after each feature)