# How to have request details of all apis call in console log like Karate.prevRequest

Tags: karate

i want get request details of all api calls in console log  like Karate.prevRequest
but by using karate.configure( ) method so i dont have to write Karate.prevRequest in all scenarios
is there any provision for this in karate framework?

Request details like this:

```
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": [
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ],
        "Authorization": [
          "Basic =="
        ],
        "Content-Length": [
          "74"
        ],
        "Host": [
          ""
        ],
        "Connection": [
          "Keep-Alive"
        ],
        "User-Agent": [
          "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14 (Java/11.0.16.1)"
        ],
        "Accept-Encoding": [
          "gzip,deflate"
        ]
      },
      "method": "POST",
      "body": "",
      "url": ""
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is the [RuntimeHook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475). It has `beforeHttpCall` and `afterHttpCall` [methods](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.5.0.RC3/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/RuntimeHook.java).