How get a REST API endpoints coverage test report in Java
I have a spring-boot project with existing unit tests and Karate integration tests that interact with my application during my maven build cycles and I want to have a generated report that tells me which REST API endpoints are interacted with and are covered by my existing tests.
I would like to generate a report similar to swagger-coverage report as depicted in this image:
enter image description here

I tried to configure Karate library to generate such reports but it is very much dependent on heavy customization and just adds information to existing scenario's and would add much wait on maintainability of the application.
I considered using Swagger-Coverage library from github https://github.com/viclovsky/swagger-coverage but it does not seem to support Karate configuration and needs code based approach to insert itself and make the reports possible


You can do this via Hooks, and here is a blog post someone wrote about it: Link.
Information about the RuntimeHook can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475
Yes ideally it should be part of Karate, maybe it will happen in the future.
