Karate with Gradle - karate-json.txt reports missing stepLog for http requests
We are trying to get the verbose details of requests logged in the report files for a karate (gradle) project, and are unable to do so (no stepLog is attached in the report for METHOD steps, and unable to expand this step hence in the html reports).
In the karate-config.js we are globally configuring the report to print as verbose
karate.configure('report', { showLog: true, showAllSteps: true, showCallArg: true });

The logback.xml karate logger is set to DEBUG
<logger name="com.intuit.karate" level="DEBUG"/>

And the build.gradle is configured to use these karate dependencies
'com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:1.4.0'
'com.intuit.karate:karate-core:1.4.0'

What could be preventing the stepLog from appending?

most likely some library conflict. see if this helps: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2436 - and for advanced needs consider the runtime-hook: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475

Thanks @PeterThomas - turns out we had to include 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.5.6' in our build.gradle - although there were no specific dependency errors with the logback.xml itself
